# Can you update a number in one spot and have it change wherever it is referenced?

Tags: rust

I want to write a program that will have many (maybe tens to hundreds) of references to the same number, say, "x" that will be updated multiple times per second. So I would like to just change the number in one place and have all the references to automatically be updated without having to reassign them (again, because there may be hundreds of them, leading to hundreds of reassignments.). If I can just update the number in one place, then I can run hundreds of product() updates right away.

Below is my attempt at this, where I have two structs referring to the same piece of f64 memory. I would like to update x one time only, and then all instances of my struct, thing1 and thing2, to calculate `product` correctly.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Thing<'a> {
    high: &'a f64,

    low: &'a f64,
}

impl Thing<'_> {
    pub fn product(&self) -> f64 {
        *self.high * *self.low
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: f64 = 42.01;
    let y: f64 = 7.95;
    let w: f64 = 99.9;
    let mut thing1: Thing = Thing { high: &w, low: &x };
    let mut thing2: Thing = Thing { high: &y, low: &x };
    println!("Before {:?} {}", thing1, thing1.product());
    println!("Before {:?} {}", thing2, thing2.product());

    // I want to swap or copy in a new value for the reference x, because
    // it appears multiple times in different `Thing`s.
    x = 500.7_f64;
    println!("After {:?} {}", thing1, thing1.product());
    println!("After {:?} {}", thing2, thing2.product());
}
```

The code above fails to compile with this error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:25:5
   |
18 |     let mut thing1: Thing = Thing { high: &w, low: &x };
   |                                                    -- borrow of `x` occurs here
...
25 |     x = 500.7_f64;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `x` occurs here
26 |     println!("After {:?} {}", thing1, thing1.product());
   |                               ------ borrow later used here
```

Comment: You cannot with shared references (which are immutable) or mutable references (which are exclusive). But there exist other ways: Try out `Rc<RefCell<T>>>` (single threaded) or `Arc<Mutex<T>>` (multi threaded) where T is the type of the shared variable (and read some docs on this subject).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) which is, along with its cousin [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), designed for the use case of modifying a shared value:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Thing<'a> {
    high: &'a Cell<f64>,
    low: &'a Cell<f64>,
}

impl Thing<'_> {
    pub fn product(&self) -> f64 {
        self.high.get() * self.low.get()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Cell::new(42.01);
    let y = Cell::new(7.95);
    let w = Cell::new(99.9);
    let thing1: Thing = Thing { high: &w, low: &x };
    let thing2: Thing = Thing { high: &y, low: &x };
    println!("Before {:?} {}", thing1, thing1.product());
    println!("Before {:?} {}", thing2, thing2.product());

    x.set(500.7_f64);
    println!("After {:?} {}", thing1, thing1.product());
    println!("After {:?} {}", thing2, thing2.product());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fda394b46f877a0c59b9b686c2ddc7d3)

Comment: This is so awesome. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, isn't having shred mutable state kind of being naughty in Rust? Is there a way to do this in a more idiomatic Rust way? Could we rewrite this without having the shared mutable state? Would it be better to clone the new values in the tens to hundreds of spots where it is repeated? That would use more CPU, but I guess it would make it thread safe?

Comment: @DavidBeckwith *isn't having shred mutable state kind of being naughty in Rust* - that's a matter of perspective, but I'd say the answer is a resounding **no**. Rust makes you declare mutable state _on a type system level_ (by using `Cell` or equivalent), which makes it perfectly clear what you can expect to happen, and when. (For example, `Cell` is not `Sync`, so you never need to worry about another thread mutating the values as you are calculating `product()`.) Of course mutable state is best avoided when possible, but sometimes it's not possible or would just produce less clear code.

Comment: *Could we rewrite this without having the shared mutable state* - maybe, but that would require major architectural changes and would no longer answer this question; consider just the question's title.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** If the type used is copyable, then you should go with [user4815162342's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258010/2470818) *(which in this case it is as it's a `f64`)*

---

To be able to do that, you could use a [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) (reference counted) [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), i.e. [`Rc<RefCell<f64>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html). If you need to be able to share it across multiple threads, then you'd need an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) instead along with a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html).

However, note that if `x` is mutably borrowed ([`borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut)), and you attempt to [`borrow()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow) elsewhere, then that will result in a panic. So if those cases can happen, then consider using [`try_borrow()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.try_borrow) and [`try_borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.try_borrow_mut).

---

I'm only applying it to `x`/`low`, but in short your `struct` would look like this:

```rust
struct Thing<'a> {
    high: &'a f64,
    low: Rc<RefCell<f64>>,
}

impl Thing<'_> {
    pub fn product(&self) -> f64 {
        *self.high * *self.low.borrow()
    }
}
```

You'd create the instances like this:

```
let mut x = Rc::new(RefCell::new(42.01));

let mut thing1: Thing = Thing {
    high: &w,
    low: x.clone(),
};

let mut thing2: Thing = Thing {
    high: &y,
    low: x.clone(),
};
```

Then lastly you can modify `x` by calling [`borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) like this:

```
*x.borrow_mut() = 500.7;
```

Comment: Note that you don't need reference counting to use a `RefCell` - in this case a shared reference would do just as well. Also, `Cell` is cheaper than `RefCell` and should be used whenever you can replace the whole value and don't need an actual reference to it, as is the case with `f64`.

Comment: Yes, `Cell` is a much better fit for this use case than an `Rc<RefCell<f64>>`

Comment: Oh, of course, because the type used is copyable. Guess I was a bit quick in my thinking.

Comment: `Cell` doesn't actually require copyable types, though it's a common misconception that it does (and it in fact used to, which is where the misconception likely comes from). The difference compared to `RefCell` is that `Cell` doesn't provide a way to obtain a _reference_ to the underlying value, mutable or otherwise, not even for the purpose of cloning the value. If the value is `Copy`, you can `get()` it by copying. But if not, you can still `replace()` it with a different value, or `take()` it, which replaces it with the default (if it's `Default`).

Comment: @user4815162342 Sure, but in the context of your example, you'd not be able to call `get()` if the type was not copyable, which is what I was referring to. Sure you could `replace()` or `take()` but that would deviate from the behavior OP expected. Alone `derive(Debug)` would not be possible if not `Copy`, for the same reason you just mentioned.

Comment: I guess you could do without `get()` in `product()` by replacing the value with a dummy one and then restoring the old value (after cloning it or inspecting it or whatever), but I agree it'd be clunky, and possibly slow. But it might still be faster than `RefCell`! - it would be interesting to check.

Comment: Thank you Vallentin too! I have a lot to learn!